# Keybind for VSCode green run button?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

What is the keybind command for the green run button at the top of VSCode?
[image]

I am not using the code runner extension since it uses output instead of terminal. I just want the default VSCode run button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Manage--> Keyboard Shortcuts**, type `Run Python File in Terminal` and search, you'll find no keybindings set by default.

[image]

Click **`+`** to press desired key combination and press Enter. For example, I set `Q` as its shortcuts, then every time I press Q, it will run python file in Terminal.

Comment: maybe a dumb question, but doesn't this mean that you can write the literal character `Q` in your code without it setting off this keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do it.

1. `F5`: It will ask you for the debug configuration which you have to manually select.

[image: Debug Config]

2. `Ctrl` + `F5`: It will simply execute the script without Debug mode.