# Is there a way get green run button for python files?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I used to have a green run button for my python files in VScode, on both Windows and Linux.
Like this image that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666687/keybind-for-vscode-green-run-button):

[image: green run button]

But now there is a boring white button instead (on Linux):

[image: boring white button]

The same thing happened to a few of my friends.

Is there a way to get the green button back?

Comment: you can set VS Code theme

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali It didn't change anything.

Comment: but you should do it now

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali Why?

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali in none of the themes I have the button gets a color, its always grey (light or dark)

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307949/color-theme-for-vs-code-integrated-terminal#:~:text=VSCode%20comes%20with%20in%2Dbuilt,%2B%20K%20%2B%20T%20on%20mac.

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali What does it have to do with my question?

Comment: you change the look of whole terminal by using there

Comment: The run button doesn't have anything to do with the terminal.

Comment: look in the long list of themable colors, if you can't find a usable theme name it can't be done, if you find one use `settings.json` to customize the theme

Comment: I just saw a CS extension with colored buttons, so just locate the svg with the run button in the VSC program directory and change its color

Comment: @rioV8 Can you put a link to it?

Comment: you want to change that button, so scan the SVG's in the software directory and change the triangles, if it one of the codicons you have a problem, you can inspect that with the developer tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding this line:

```
.action-label.codicon.codicon-play{color:#89d185}
```

To this file: `/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.css`